# How to break used base64 code with exec in python

Tags: python, base64, exec

How to break used base64 code with exec in python

```
import base64

exec(base64.b64encode('I0NvZGVkIGJ5IGNhbnBvbGF0Z2==')
```

Comment: You probably want `b64decode` instead of `b64encode`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
import base64
print(base64.b64decode('I0NvZGVkIGJ5IGNhbnBvbGF0Z2=='))
## b'#Coded by canpolatg'
```

Answer (score -1):

To decode base64 encoded data in Python you can use base64.b64decode

```
base64.b64decode(b'I0NvZGVkIGJ5IGNhbnBvbGF0Z2==')
# b'#Coded by canpolatg'
```